# How to open external site in component angular?

Tags: angular

I have an idea, but I don't know how to make it happen.

I have an application (angular+electron+sqlite) , and it operates on a database, currently executes a script that retrieves data from a certain page (description of the script (www.Cisowscy.com/Software/haploFT), then manually adds these files to the application, which after processing adds them to the database, on which the application later conducts analysis.

I would like to avoid the need to go to second window (Google chrome) and execute this script. I would like the user to be able to display the project of his choice inside the component, and the application would download from it the data that the user needs, and then they would process themselves, and so on. (As it is now).

The question is how to force a external website (from external domen), to be loaded in (isolated?) a box, an the this child component?

And how to, get into the "DOM" of this loaded page, from parent componet.

And how to release the memory from the huge amount of data loaded from this page when closing the component.

Someone should have an idea how to start..., how to get started?

Thank you very much in advance for your help. 
P.s. I was looking for some ideas on google a day and a half, but unsuccessfully.

---

Why is @stackoverflow .com harassing me? They gave me blue field a "Got a question that you can’t ask on public Stack Overflow? Learn more about sharing private information with Stack Overflow for Teams." label, but in my question, there is nothing that defines it. ? Why?!

Comment: Hi! What you are possibly looking for is a component with a [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) that loads an external url where simply dynamically create it with a reference and then simply remove the nodes reference when needed

Comment: @Lucho , Thank you, I'm gonna try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Try this:-

## .html

```
 <iframe id="" class="" height="100%" width="100%" style="border: 0;" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

## DomSanitizerPipe.pipe.ts

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'domSanitizer'
})
export class DomSanitizerPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(htmlString: string, args?: any): any {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlString);
    }

}
```

## .ts

```
   constructor(
        public sanitizer:DomSanitizer
    ) { 
        this.urlSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://.....');
    }
```

## 2) get into the "DOM" of this loaded page, from parent component.

## .ts

```
window.parent.someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow(data);

//someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow is defined in electron app/ other iframe loaded //app
```

## 3) calling method defined in component.ts from iframe app

## index.html

```
     <app-root></app-root>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//updateFromDevice is called from iframe
            function updateFromDevice(data) {
                window['componentRef'].zone.run(() => {
                    window['componentRef'].component.updateFromIframe(data);
                });
            }
        </script>
```

## app.component.ts

```
 constructor(
        private zone: NgZone,
    ) {
        window['componentRef'] = {
            zone: this.zone,
            componentFn: (value) => this.updateFromIframe(value),
            component: this
        };
    }

  updateFromIframe(data) {}
```